# Xamarin Forms: binding image in listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to xamarin forms and i'd like to know the best approach to bind an image from uri in a listview.

The scenario is the following:

1. A listview that get remote json data from a web services
2. The json data contains many url
3. Each cell get async the image and show it
4. I want reuse of the cell

What's the best approach with xamarin forms? I haven't found any tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example, but basically, create a ListView, bind your collection of objects (the url field here is called `ImageUrl`), then set that as the source of an `Image` element in a `ViewCell` of your `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding MyCollectionOfThings}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Yep, but this example works with reuse of cell strategy?

Comment: Yeah, cell recycling is baked into Xamarin.Forms now.